# Recursive decoding of URI component in python like javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, urllib2

I have a encoded URI component `"http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-caf%25C3%25A9-houston-2"`. I could able to convert this to `"http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-café-houston-2"` by applying decodeURIComponent function recursively as below

```
function recursiveDecodeURIComponent(uriComponent){
        try{
            var decodedURIComponent = decodeURIComponent(uriComponent);
            if(decodedURIComponent == uriComponent){
                return decodedURIComponent;
            }
            return recursiveDecodeURIComponent(decodedURIComponent);
        }catch(e){
            return uriComponent;
        }
    }
    console.log(recursiveDecodeURIComponent("http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-caf%25C3%25A9-houston-2"))
```

Outputs: `"http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-café-houston-2"`.

I would like to get the same in python.
I tried the following:

```
print urllib2.unquote(urllib2.unquote(urllib2.unquote("http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-caf%25C3%25A9-houston-2").decode("utf-8")))
```

but I got `http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-cafÃ©-houston-2`. Instead of Expected character `é`, I got `'Ã©'` irrespective of any number of calling urllib2.unquote.

I am using python2.7.3, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a simple loop should do the trick:

```
uri = "http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-caf%25C3%25A9-houston-2"

while True:
    dec = urllib2.unquote(uri)
    if dec == uri:
        break
    uri = dec

uri = uri.decode('utf8')
print '%r' % uri  
# u'http://www.yelp.com/biz/carriage-house-caf\xe9-houston-2'
```

Comment: my bad, I was just testing something else and got put off by mixed encoded/non-encoded unquoting.. nevermind :)